# Eclipse Scala IDE code not compiling

Tags: eclipse, scala

I downloaded eclipse scala ide from scala-ide.org site and trying to compile my first scala word count program. But its gives error "object not a member of package org" in the following import command

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

After some research I found that I need to add the jar file spark-assembly-1.0.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar to overcome this issue

But after doing lot of research I could not locate this jar. Can anyone help here  ?

Comment: Rather than looking for a specific jar, I'd suggest having a maven project and adding spark as a maven dependency (either manually in pom.xml or using the right click menu). Eclipse/Scala IDE integrates with maven. and this way your dependencies are declared in a file (that you can e.g. check into version control) rather than just in your eclipse configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is not a simple language/env to learn. It is important you learn how scala works and then move into spark.
There are tons of material available on web. A proper learning path will be to learn
SBT > SCALA > Use Scala for Spark

The dependency that you mentioned, can be put in he sbt's build.sbt. You can also use maven, but I recommend learning sbt as way of learning scala. Once you have resolved, the dependency using SBT, your simple code should work fine. But still, I recommend doing a "hello world" first than doing a "word count" :-)

Ando to answer your question, in your SBT you should be adding following library,

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-assembly_2.10" % "1.1.1"
```

This was for spark assembly 1.1.1 for hadoop 2.10. I see you need a different version, you can find the proper version at

[Maven Repo details for spark/hadoop](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-assembly_2.10/1.1.1)

Here's the pure eclipse solutions (I had to download and setup eclipse just to answer this question)

1. Get Scala IDE (it comes with inbuilt Scala Compiler version 2.10.5 and 2.11.6)
2. Create a new project Scala Wizard > Scala Project
3. Right click "src" in the scale project , select "Scala Object", give it a name - I gave WordCount
4. Right click project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project
5. In the body of word count object (I named the object as WordCount) paste the text from [Apache Spark Example](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) which finally looks like

```

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object WordCount {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleTest")
    val spark = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val textFile = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
    val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                                   .map(word => (word, 1))
                                   .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
}
```

```
6. Add following to your maven

```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```

7. Right click on "Scala Library Container", and select "Latest 2.10 bundle", click ok
8. Once I was done with these, there was no error message displayed on my "problems" list of Eclipse...indicating that it compiled as expected.
9. Obviously, this example won't run as I haven't provided enough info for it to run...but this was just to answer to the question, "how to get the code compiled".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you motivating speech. I am working on scala since last 1 year. But yes writing code in eclipse using scala ide is new to me . I want to compile the code in eclipse and execute it using submit command. if you know anything about it do let me know.. Else you can ignore the question..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using SBT at this stage - it isn't scala but rather its own (complex) thing on top of scala, and its eclipse integration is much worse than maven's. (Ultimately if you want to release scala libraries for other people to use you will probably have to learn SBT, as maven cannot easily cross-build something to work with multiple versions of scala, but in the meantime maven is much simpler and nicer to use).

Comment: @lmm I agree with you that SBT is not as simple as maven. But it is worth the effort, if you are planning to make scala as language of choice.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the explanation but I tried the way you suggested but it did not worked. Still it did not recognized the import statements

Comment: Can you paste lines from "problems" tab in scala IDE ?

Comment: Missed one critical step...just aded #4 , please try now.

Comment: Due to my busy schedule could not respond. But yeah it works now with Group ID: org.apache.spark
 Artifact ID: spark-core_2.11
Version: 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

- Install the SBT Scala build+dependency tool
- Create an empty directory. Name it spark-test or whatever you want to name your project.
- Put your source code in the sub-directory src/scala/main. If you have Main.scala in package scalatest, it should be src/scala/main/scalatest/Main.scala
- Make a build.sbt file with the following contents

  name := """sparktest"""

  version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0"
  )
- Configure the SBT Eclipse plugin. Create ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt, with:

  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
- Generate an Eclipse project with `sbt eclipse`
- Import your project into eclipse.
- Run :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestin Clay. This will work.. But in very simple terms can we know which jar file has all the properties for org.apache.spark The solution should be very simple in eclipse if we can add this library here then the code will get compiled and in spark-submit as we already have all the required jar that will execute the program. Do let me know if my understanding is wrong

Comment: @Peter2711 : The jar files listed in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark has all the dependencies. I don't think there's any "single" jar that will have all dependencies. However, the solution I provided above has the jar file mentioned.

Comment: spark-core has one single .jar file. However, that .jar file depends on many other .jar files. You need _all_ of those. It's not practical to handle that manually. You basically need a build+dependency tool like Maven, Gradle, or SBT. I understand you want to avoid the complexity of build+dependency tools right now, but it's basically necessary to work with Java/Scala beyond super simple zero-dependency tasks.

Comment: As @javadevg says, you can try manually downloading from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/1.4.0, but you may get runtime issues if you run outside of spark-submit and you don't have the transitive dependencies setup.